# Blazor - Doing authenticated login

Tags: authentication, blazor

I am trying to login using blazor.

Blazor.Bootstrap - version 1.11.1

blazor-dragdrop - version 2.6.1

.NET 8.0.

Major goal is to do login properly, and keep the user logged in after login process.

For the following, I can do NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged only, but it is not enough, since I the user is not kept login (no cookie etc.)

In C# code, after checking for user+password that are OK, I tried calling the login:

```
public async Task Login(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, string username, string password)
{
    List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim> { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username) };

    ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);


    ClaimsPrincipal user = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
    await httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, user);
    NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(user)));

}
```

In startup.cs, In ConfigurationService method, I wrote:

```
...
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, CustomAuthenticationStateProvider>();
...
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.Name = "auth_token";
        options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
        options.LoginPath = "/login";
        options.Cookie.MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
        options.AccessDeniedPath = "/access-denied";
    });

services.AddAuthorization();
services.AddCascadingAuthenticationState();
```

and in startup.cs, Configure method:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

For the line, starts with (it is essential creating the token, cookie, etc):
await httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.SignInAsync

I encountered an error:

> Error: System.InvalidOperationException: OnStarting cannot be set
> because the response has already started.    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ThrowResponseAlreadyStartedException(String
> value)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.OnStarting(Func`2 callback, Object state)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler.InitializeHandlerAsync() at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.InitializeAsync(AuthenticationScheme
> scheme, HttpContext context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandlerProvider.GetHandlerAsync(HttpContext
> context, String authenticationScheme)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.SignInAsync(HttpContext
> context, String scheme, ClaimsPrincipal principal,
> AuthenticationProperties properties)    ...

What may be wrong?

Whether I change the way I do login:

```
public class CustomAuthenticationStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
...
public async Task Login(string username, string password)
{
    // Authentication logic here (e.g., validate username and password)
    // For simplicity, let's assume the user is authenticated successfully

    List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim> { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username) };
    ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    ClaimsPrincipal userPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

    // This line updates the authentication state across the Blazor app
    NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(userPrincipal)));
}
```

and calling Login, I do:

```
[Inject]
private AuthenticationStateProvider CustomStateProvider { get; set; }
...
AuthenticationState authState = await CustomStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
```

and I see that authState.Identity.Claims.Count = 0;

authState.Identity.Claims.Count should have at least 1 value.

Is there something special I should write in startup.cs in order that the above work properly? Probably need bearer token + cookie.

Comment: Specify the exact Blazor version and starter template. Startup.cs sounds very ancient.

Comment: Blazor.Bootstrap - version 1.11.1

blazor-dragdrop - version 2.6.1

.NET 8.0.

Comment: If Blazor 8 why do you have a `startup.cs,`?  Everything should be in Program.  and what Render mode?

Comment: I got the project as is. I don't know why startup.cs included. Maybe old version conversion. Does this matter? Also the use is of visual-studio community.

Comment: You can still use the old `startup.cs`, but with the new conventions and styles you're better off moving everything to the `Program.cs`, like @MrCakaShaunCurtis noted

Comment: I still can't tell what Interactivity is being used here, and not completely certain everything was upgraded to v8.

Comment: This is an educated guess but " OnStarting cannot be set because the response has already started." suggests you are trying to write the security headers to the page after it has been created i.e. within the Blazor Hub (server or WASM).  I believe your first block of code [using the HttpContextAccessor] can only be written during server side pre-rendering in the HttpRequest pipelline.  My guess is you are trying to make a  server side rendered login page into an actively rendered page.

Comment: The render mode is: ServerPrerendered.
I want to combine cookie with bearer token.
So after login there will be a bearer token, but it should be kept in cookie (for a certain time).